# Delete items older than a week

Tags: powershell

```
$date =  (Get-Date).AddDays(-7).ToString('dd/MM/yyyy')

Get-ChildItem  -Path c:\Filestore  | Where-Object { ($_.CreationTime).ToString('dd/MM/yyyy') -lt $date } | remove-item
```

I want all items in the folder c:\Filestore to be delete if 1 week old or older. 
When I test out this script it doesn't seem to delete anything I'm not sure if I'm missing something.

I call on the date 7 days ago and then list all items in c:\Filestore where the date equals that of 7 days ago and delete them.

Answer (score 1):

You *don't* want to compare **strings**, you *want* to compare **dates**. - so just remove the `ToString()` invokes:

```
$date =  (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\Filestore | Where-Object CreationTime -lt $date | remove-item
```